# How to open AppStore and show specific apps?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

From within an app, I'd like to open up the iOS App Store and show some specific apps. They'll be from different developers, so I can't take that shortcut. Is there a way to list apps by ID, or somehow use specific search terms?

For example, how could I show just the Facebook and Twitter apps?

Here are some links that work, but will just show one app or one search term...

```
itms://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=307538288

itms-apps://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=Sea+Lion+Games%2C+Inc
```

If I could use separate search terms, that should work. For example, if you try to search for "angryninjarunner", you'll get one result for iPhone and iPad: Angry Ninja Runner. If you search for "rescuejumplite" - you'll get Rescue Jump Lite. But how can I combine those two terms, so I could show both apps, if I wanted to?

For the Google Play Store, you can just add a simple "OR" between app IDs, and it'll bring 'em up, nice and easy. Trying to do the same for iOS, but it has mostly resulted in me banging my head against the keyboard.

Comment: Don't think Apple's store API allows for that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately currently there is no option available for this. If both the app contains any common terms in it's name, you can query with that term.

Comment: Poo... there's API to return several apps in a JSON format. Think any of that could transfer over to an HTML address? http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#lookup

Answer (score 0):

App review guideline

```
    2.25 Apps that display Apps other than your own for 
purchase or promotion in a manner similar to or confusing 
with the App Store will be rejected
```

AppGratis got kicked out and banned from appstore for this violation and this was added last year by Apple. So don't do it unless you plan to show your own apps.

Comment: Yes, it'll be apps we have created. :) Thanks. Trouble is, we've released apps under several different names, since we're also a contractor, but they're all by us.